# can't pass data coming from socket io as a prop to a react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, socket.io, components

I tried several ways and nothing seems to work :( I'm trying to learn React by building a simple app that implements Socket io and can't find a way to pass "response" as a prop to the child component.

```js
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import Main from "./Main";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:4001";


function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("tick", (data) => {
      setResponse(data);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(response);
 
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Main
         responses = {response}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Main.css';

class Main extends React.Component {

  render() {



   return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="placeholder">hello {this.props.responses}</div>
        <div className="placeholder"></div>
        <div className="placeholder"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I get this error

> ×
> ×
> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {currencyPairName, prices}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
> ▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
> Socket.
> src/App.js:14

```
11 | useEffect(() => {
  12 |   const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
  13 |   socket.on("tick", (data) => {
> 14 |     setResponse(data);
     | ^  15 |   });
  16 | }, []);
  17 |
```

> 

my response contains an array of objects

hope someone can show me the light..

Comment: It appears that you have a typo. `ListItems` with a capital "L" vs the variable `listItems` with lowercase.

Comment: oops sorry, I fixed it now.  still get an error but a different one..

Comment: In `Main` you have `const arr = this.props.responses;` when you probably want `const arr = this.props.arr;` since that is the name of the prop. Additionally, `listItems` is mapping over `responses`, when I think you want `arr.map()`

Comment: here I try to map the responses and the console just ignores the "details" prop  `<div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>  {Object.keys(response).map(key => <Response key={key} details=         {response[key]}         />)}         <Main          responses = {response}         />       </div>     </>   ); }`

Comment: I also get this error message:Uncaught Error: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store.

Comment: dummy data gets me the same results! this is what I'm sending: `const arr1 = [{currencyPairName: "USD / ILS",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}},
               {currencyPairName: "EUR / USD",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}},
               {currencyPairName: "EUR / USD",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}}]`